# I need to print out the taxable income from the mthod that i called in the main method. however the loop in the method will only return one value

Tags: java

Here is my code, the loop in the compute tax method will only return the first nmber which isnt even correct. how can i return the correct value. In each loop there must be a type of tax bracket choosen which you enter a number 1-4. this will also go to the method loop as well.

```
public class TaxTable
{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(" Enter in status\n (1 for single\n,2 for married joint, 3 for Married         separate, 4 for Head of House: ");
        int status = scan.nextInt();
        //if status to print out status name
        if (status == 1)
            System.out.println ("Taxable\t single\nIncome");
        else if (status == 2)
            System.out.println ("Taxable\tMarried Jointly\nQualified Widow\nIncome");
        else if (status == 3)
            System.out.println ("Taxable\tMarried separate\nIncome");
        else if (status == 4)
            System.out.println ("Taxable\tHead of House\nIncome");
        int taxableIncome = 50000;


        for (int i = 50000; i <= 60000; i += 50)
            System.out.println (i + "\t" + Math.round(computeTax(status, taxableIncome)));

    }

    public static double computeTax (int status, double taxableIncome) {
        double tax=0;
        for (int k = 50000; k <= 60000; k =+ 50) {
            if (status == 1)
                taxableIncome = 4675 + ((k-33950)*.25);
            else if(status == 2)
                taxableIncome = 16701 + (k-16701)*.15;
            else if(status == 3)
                taxableIncome = 4675 + (k-33951)*.25;
            else if(status == 4)
                taxableIncome = 6227.5 + (k-33549)*.25;
            return taxableIncome[k];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: originally i had the return statement be return taxableIncome which also did not work

Comment: You've got a return statement in there; the loop will never progress past the first iteration.

Comment: so then how should i return all of the values needed to the main method

Comment: Use an array `double[] taxableIncome` as second parameter of your `computeTax(...)` method. You probably did something like that already because you try to return an array element `taxableIncome[k]` (though there is no such array). Supply an array to `computeTax(...)` that is big enough to hold all values. Fill the array inside the method. Access the array values outside the method. `computeTax(...)` can be of type `void,` i.e. it isn't supposed to return anything then.

Comment: is there a way to do that without arrays. we havent covered those in class yet

Comment: Yes it is, but omit the extra method, do it all in `main(...)` then.

Comment: I am required to use the extra method, so how should i go about that with out arrays.

Comment: To confirm, is it the intention of the program to calculate the tax based on the status for every increment of $50 from $50,000 to $60,000?

Answer (score -1):

To "return" multiple values without using an array, set a global variable within the method and then return the second value. Here is some concept code.

```
public static double returnVal2;

public static void method(){
    double returnVal1 = otherMethod();
    // returnVal1 now holds 1 return value, and returnVal2 now holds the other.
}

public static double otherMethod(){
    returnVal2 = 0; // Change 0 to second value that you want to return.
    return 0;       // Change 0 to the first value that you want to return.
}
```

Comment: This is a really bad idea and btw. it's not an answer to op's question.

Comment: The OP wanted to know how to return multiple values without using arrays, I know that this is not ideal, but it's the best that can be done giving the OP's constraints. @DirkLachowski

Comment: Downvote is not from me, but really: A method returning a value and as a side effect modifying a global variable to "return" a second value? What about returning an object?